# How to click Browser back button in Safari using selenium/javascript

Tags: selenium, browser, safari, automation

I am using selenium automation in Safari. It seems there is an issue in using `driver.navigate.back()`

So I used:

```
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("history.back")
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("history.go(-1)")
```

But this code is going to the previous page and not actually clicking the browser back button. I confirmed by doing manually. If I do manually in my application, it will pop up a dialog saying "do you want to leave this page?"  But with this code it's not happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on this [open issue](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=3771), it seems Safari reloads an old page.  It doesn't fully initialize the extension for the page.

Hence Selenium [does not support it](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/javascript/safari-driver/inject/commands.js?spec=svnc31aea4cb6e9c8f6d75fa8533c990aba55f2d407&r=c31aea4cb6e9c8f6d75fa8533c990aba55f2d407#71):

```
safaridriver.inject.commands.unsupportedHistoryNavigation = function() {
  throw Error('Yikes! Safari history navigation does not work. We can ' +
      'go forward or back, but once we do, we can no longer ' +
      'communicate with the page...');
};
```